# Best way to store Geo locations details in Cassandra and Indexes in Elastic Search?

Tags: elasticsearch, cassandra, geolocation, geopoints

Amit here, 
My problem is 
I want to store Geo related details in Cassandra and their index in Elastic search for faster access. 
I want to store Country name, country ISO code , State/region,city name along with Latitude and longitude. I can use geopoint in Elastic search for storing Lat/long but unable to get anything about Cassandra. What should be the data type?
So please suggests me the way to store geo details in Cassandra / Elastic search

Amit

Answer (score 1):

You can create own user-defined type with **Cassandra**

```
CREATE TYPE geopoint (
   latitude double,
   longitude double,
)

CREATE TABLE geodetails(
     object_id uuid,
     country text,
     country_iso_codex text,
     state text,
     region text,
     city text,
     location frozen<geopoint>,
     PRIMARY KEY(object_id)  
);
```

Pay attention to the **frozen<geopoint>** syntax

Answer (score 1):

The solution proposed by @doandyhai is good if you just want to store the lat-lng but wont be helpful incase of querying the data.

You should be using **PointType** to store the lat-lng and over this, you can perform geospatial queries.

```
//CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE test (
id text PRIMARY KEY, 
point 'PointType', 
linestring 'LineStringType');

// Insert Query
INSERT INTO test (id, point, linestring) 
VALUES ('1', 'POINT(5 50)', 'LINESTRING (30 10, 10 30, 40 40)' );

//Find points within a 10 unit radius from point (4, 49):
SELECT * FROM test 
WHERE solr_query= '{ "q":"*:*", "fq":"point:\"IsWithin(BUFFER(POINT(4.0 49.0), 10.0))\"" }';
```

**SOURCE**: Datastax Cassandra Docs Geospatial queries.

For more ref use this [link](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.7/cql/cql/cql_using/search_index/queriesGeoSpatial.html)

FYI: Before firing the queries setup Solr Core: https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/datastax_enterprise/5.0/datastax_enterprise/srch/creatingCoreCustomIndexResources.html